# Looping though columns to store in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

So I have a DataTable which uses a "SELECT * FROM People WHERE ID = ?" you can understand that this will only retrieve one row as the ID is unique

I have casted it to a list:

```
   List<DataTable> userInfo = (List<DataTable>)HttpContext.Current.Session["userDT"];
```

Now I am trying to do a foreach loop that would loop through each row and store the column into a session, this is what I have so far:

However I get an error:

**Cannot convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Data.DataRow'**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't store it as a DataRow or a plain value in the session. Instead, create a class that holds the properties you want to store, and store that in the session.

Answer (score 0):

userInfo is a list of tables.  You have to iterate through it, and for each table you can access that table's rows:

```
        foreach (DataTable dt in userInfo)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                // if you want column names here is how you would get them
                string columnName = column.ColumnName;

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    // if you want the values in the cells, here's where you get them
                    object value = row[column];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So how would I store a column like first_name into a session?

Comment: Are you asking how you would access the value in the column named "first_name"?  Or are you looking for column names?